# mysql query request regarding group by

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have 2 tables like bellow:

t1

```
+-----------+------------+----------+
| ProductID |  old_repo  | new_repo |
+-----------+------------+----------+
|         1 |     14B    |    15A   |
+-----------+------------+----------+
```

t2

```
+-----------+------------+
| repoName  |  repo_build|
+-----------+------------+
|   14B     |   CSX_12   |
+-----------+------------+
|   15A     |   CSX_13   |
+-----------+------------+
```

from this I want to get the following selection

```
+------------+----------+
|   CSX_12   |   CSX_13 |
+------------+----------+
```

That is I want to get both old_repo and new_repo's repo_build that is in t1 where ProductID='1' in t1. How can this be done?

```
select old_repo,new_repo from t1 where ProductIdD='1'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it the following way:

```
SELECT a.repo_build
      ,b.repo_build
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 a ON a.repoName = t1.old_repo
LEFT JOIN t2 b ON B.repoName = t1.new_repo 
where ProductID ='1'
```

[**SQLFiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9ce2d)